# A selector switch id with jquery as condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, anchor

perhaps too easy what I ask, or maybe not. Anyway, I need to call a certain anchor of the page as the link is pressed, it enters a particular URL with a particular Anchor scroll down to that anchor.

I'm doing it with jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var anchor = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    if(anchor!="") {

        var newAnchor= "'#anchor-" +anchor+"'";

        $(newAnchor).trigger("click");

    }

});
```

I think this is not possible be, I certainly have never seen it, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#anchor-2015'
```

Is it possible to call a selector dynamically like this? Was there another way?

Thank you.

Comment: `window.location.hash = "anchor-" +ancla;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You have wrong the quotes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var anchor = window.location.hash.substring(1);


if(anchor!=""){

    var newAnchor= "#anchor-" + anchor;

    $(newAnchor).trigger("click");


    }


});
```

Comment: Great, great. Sometimes they are so simple and yet so complex errors. The solution in front of me and I can not see it. : D

Comment: You still have the extra quote before `#`.

Answer (score 3):

Remove single quotes, they are not needed.

```
var newAnchor= "#ancla-" + anchor;
```

Comment: Great !! I took hours browsing without success. Awesome. :D